# Attribute error occurs every time i try to extract only the tweet using Tweepy?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

This code is to search for tweets with a certain keyword and extract the most relevant tweets that matches the set of keywords in my CSV file.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import pandas as pd
import nltk

def tokened(a):
    return nltk.word_tokenize(a)
i=0
j=0
doc = pd.read_csv('Finder.csv')

#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey="nothing"
csecret="nothing"
atoken="nothing"
asecret="nothing"
class listener(StreamListener):

      def on_data(self, status):

              k=(status.text)
              z=tokened(k)
              for txt in z:

                  for txt2 in doc['NEET'][j]:
                      j=j+1
                      if (txt.upper().lower() == 'RT'):
                          break
                      elif (txt.upper().lower() == txt2.upper().lower()):
                            api.update_status("Try", 
in_reply_to_status_id=status.id)
                            print(status.text)



      def on_error(self, status):
            print(status)

auth=OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)



twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['Neet'])
```

I get this error all the time :

> k=(status.text)
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

The main error is in `k=(status.text)`:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: I suggest you republish question to save you secret data. Remove all sensitive information

Comment: Well it tells you what the problem is, no? `status` is a string, so you can't do `status.text`. It already is the text

Answer (score 0):

`status` is a string in json format, to access its elements you have to decode it with the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Instead of:

```
k=(status.text)
```

You should do:

```
k = json.loads(status)['text']
```

Comment: Thanks man. Now i get this error                                                                   ''for txt2 in doc['NEET'][j]:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment''

Comment: Yeah, you have to give a value to `j` first, maybe 0. But what do you intend with `'for txt2 in doc['NEET'][j]`? Because you seem to be changing the iterator inside of it's own loop. The purpose is not clear.

Comment: Yeah, that error is resolved now. I'm getting this now " **tweepy.error.TweepError: Expecting length, unexpected value found** " . Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: It seems to be a problem in tweepy own implementation. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442616/tweeperror-expecting-length-unexpected-value-found-pandas-jupyter-notebook/44329610#44329610](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442616/tweeperror-expecting-length-unexpected-value-found-pandas-jupyter-notebook/44329610#44329610)